# Reports in VB6 is not working from remote desktop

Tags: vb6, rdp

While working from home I am using a VB6 application on remote desktop. Everything working fine but whenever I am trying to open any report in it, it is showing

"Run-time error '9':
Subscript out of range.

and application get closed. But while opening from local system everything works fine.
Both systems are Windows 8.1 (64 bit).

Comment: Are there any runtime-loaded components?

Comment: It would be useful to see the code where you open the report.

Comment: Seems likely to be something specific the app is doing; I use VB6 stuff over RDP all the time w/o issue.

Comment: The error `Subscript out of range` indicates that the program is trying to access an element of an array that is outside of its bounds.  Do you have access to the source code or able to debug the program to determine which line it is failing on?